# vba code for matching 1st & last string between 2 columns and getting result in the third column in excel

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA code. Need help in matching strings with a Macro. Have a system name "John Jerome Doss" in Col A and Input Name in "John J Doss" in Column B. I want to compare the first and last string in columns A & B and if 1st and last string match, the result in Column C should be "OK" else the column C should be "Check".

PS: The format in Column A is "FirstName-MiddleName-LastName" & The format in Column B is "FirstName-Intial-LastName".

I am not sure of the coding for this. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You can google ***Instr() function for vba*** for a start

Comment: Have'nt done anything yet.. will google for instr () function and try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of arrays split on the space character should do this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub firstLastCheck()
    Dim vals As Variant, n1 As Variant, n2 As Variant, chk As Variant, i As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        vals = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2
        ReDim chk(LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1), 1 To 1)
        For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            n1 = Split(vals(i, 1), Chr(32))
            n2 = Split(vals(i, 2), Chr(32))
            If LCase(n1(LBound(n1))) = LCase(n2(LBound(n2))) And _
               LCase(n1(UBound(n1))) = LCase(n2(UBound(n2))) Then
                chk(i, 1) = "OK"
            Else
                chk(i, 1) = "Check"
            End If
        Next i
        .Cells(2, "C").Resize(UBound(chk, 1), UBound(chk, 2)) = chk
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This is working awesome. But if you can explain the logic for this code would be much appreciated ! And also i need to run this code only for a particular criteria "Personal" in column D.

Comment: Oh-key-doh-key, you've obviously taken the time to review the [official msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/lbound-function) for each function and operation so what specific question do have that wasn't answered there?

Answer (score 0):

Logically what you are wanting to do is just take the first and last words from a string and compare them against other values.

In practice a combination of `InStr` and `InStrRev` will allow you to split on a delimiter in this case a space (" ").

An example function to do so is below:

```
Function FormateName(str As String) As String
  FormateName = Left(str, InStr(1, str, " ") - 1) & " " & Right(str, Len(str) - InStrRev(str, " "))
End Function
```

In order to understand the above the fist section returns the cell's value up to the first space. The next concatenates with a space for readability (This is optional). The last section scans backwards for the last space and then returns the last x characters to for the last name.

The return of the function will be "FirstName LastName". From the above function you should be able to built a loop over your dataset then use the above function to strip the middle name and then perform a lookup to populate column C.

Please let us know if you have any issues creating this next step.